# Why is my Epson SureColor P600 suddenly printing weird cyan colors?

Tags: troubleshooting, printing, epson

This printer has been really good so far. Suddenly it started to print weird cyan colors. I did some nozzle check and head cleaning with no progress. Did anyone experience that?

When I did the nozzle check, it's always the last pattern that's missed up (see photo)

This is happening with both color and black and white images. I use Photoshop and I make it handle printing and color profiles.

This is also happening with different paper

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using genuine epson inks?

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft yes I do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure this question really belongs here, but will try to help as there isn't a printing stack....
As an ex Epson engineer, I can say that you (quite clearly) have no matte black feeding.

Remove the cartridge, shake it, **is it empty**?

If not **Have you left the vacuum seal tab on the cartridge?**

Comment: this should be tested quickly by switching to photo black, if your theory is correct I should get a clean print, right?

Comment: Yes correct :-) no need to do a proper print, just see if you get a good test pattern.

Comment: alright thanks, I'll give it a try it and see what'll happen

Comment: Any luck? @akram

Comment: you are right! Printing with Photo black doesn't have any problems. I doubled check the MK cartridge shacked it and installed it again and now Matte is also fine. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

If the printer printed correctly before with the same cartridges and the inks are not empty, assuming your Epson printer has the same controls as mine, which is a different model, try running a cleaning cycle and if it does not help, the deep cleaning.

Comment: what's the deep cleaning? I did head cleaning 5 times already

Comment: It's an option in my Epson 3880 printer menu, much more powerful than regular cleaning. Not sure if your printer has it.

Comment: and uses a MASSIVE amount of ink - doing the photo/matte swap will only draw on the black part of the head so not waste the rest (yes i have a 3880 too, epic printer)

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft Yes, that's a good point. Is it confirmed that the clogged pigment is not one of the light blacks though?